# Searching users on multiple databases by email without effecting performance

Tags: c#, sql, .net, performance, authentication

Current implementation:
I have one system that is been used by several thousands of customers, each customer has it's own  SQL database and has the option to login via web browser or mobile app. Today user is verified by user name, password and domain name which is equivalent to database name.
Future Requirement:
User should login only using email address and password without domain name.
This basically means that a global search has to be done on all those thousands of databases to find one user. How to make such global search without effecting performance? is there any cleaver way to work out the issue?

Comment: you would sync the database with a master database and check only against 1 database. There will always be performance reduction, as you need a connection. independent how you access it

Comment: Create a `View` which selects all e-mail addresses of all databases or just use a simple `SELECT` over all databases. Don't use the `*` wildcard, specify which column you want. SELECT performance is quite high. Insert, Update and Delete have "bad" performance as they alter indexes and stuff like that. I wouldn't worry about the impact of a SELECT statement too much.

Comment: @Max I guess that might be a feasible solution, thank you

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if you are looking for performance and you will search in each one separately, use the reverse procedure and clean ADO.NET.

Alternatively, it is possible to merge the users into a separate database as preferred and search it.

The third option is, again with the reversed procedure, to make the request extract data from as many databases as you want.